# Select box HIT area not aligned with visual placement

Tags: html, css

I have a select list in IE 8 it works ok.

On Firefox 3 and 4: I cannot click on the select box, unless I move the mouse 0.5cm below the actual select box.

On Webkit  the same as firefox, plus by default it looks blank with no options in it until clicked?

The page is http://gocruising.com.au/Cruises/Search the select list is on the right "sort results by"

I know there must be some invalid HTML somewhere but I cannot see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<div class="icons">...</div>` is hanging down, meaning the click events on the control are really click the the `div`.

You may need to make that `div` smaller, reposition it, or lift the `select` above using `z-index`.

[image: Example]

Comment: ahh I see thanks. yeah z-index does not work.  I think It will have to position .icons using float instead of position relative